# Programmatically controlling Chart in Silverlight toolkit

Tags: c#, silverlight, charts

I want to control the x and y axis of a multi series line charts available in Silverlight toolkit from the C# code. I am not able to find any appropriate example using google. Any kind of example or pointers would be appreciated!

EDIT:

This is what I have done so far:

```
<toolkit:Chart Canvas.Left="104" Canvas.Top="18" Name="chartCompare" Title="Compare Series" Height="285" Width="892">
<toolkit:LineSeries
         Title="SP1"
         Name="Series1"/>
</toolkit:Chart>
```

And in the code behind I am trying this:

```
Series1.ItemsSource = ObjectList;

Series1.IndependentValuePath = "Val1";
Series1.DependentValuePath = "Val2";
```

Where ObjectList is a List of Objects which has val1 and val2 as its property.
But it is throwing an error when I run this in Line `"Series1.ItemsSource = ObjectList;"` saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object..". I have initialised and set its value just in the line before it. Actually I have set this as an item source for a data grid in the line before it and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to add this before using the Series1:

```
//Line to be inserted
LineSeries Series1 = chart.Series[0] as LineSeries;

Series1.IndependentValuePath = "Val1";
Series1.DependentValuePath = "Val2";
Series1.ItemsSource = ObjectList;
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

i tried  your example and i got "out of index" exeption

this form is better

```
   LineSeries Series1 = new LineSeries();
    Series1.IndependentValuePath = "Val1";
    Series1.DependentValuePath = "Val2";
    Series1.ItemsSource = ObjectList;
    chart.Series.Add(Series1);
```